# Error when trying to log to papertrail?

Tags: logging, cloud-foundry, papertrail-app

I follow these simple steps precisely from this wonderful [link](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/hosting-services/cloud-foundry/)

After I binded the service with my application, and restaged it. There was no log out putting as it said it would after 30 seconds. on the link provided.

In my cf logs I can see that I am getting an error

```
ERR Syslog Sink syslog-tls://logs2.papertrailapp.com:15452: Error when dialing out. Backing off for 33.807736s. Err: dial tcp 171.46.93.161:15452: i/o timeout
```

Any help on how to fix this error would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in a port number for the service.

e.g. 145452 should be something withing 0 to 65535

You can also ssh into your app container and check if the service endpoint is accessible via nc/openssl client

Comment: I changed some of the numbers to mask mine. That did not solve my issue. I tried entering the credentials in putty, but I get a timeout error. hostname: logs12.papertrailapp.com port: 15452

Comment: If the port is right then something might be blocking access.  To test, run `cf ssh <app>`.  This will put you in the app container.  Then try connecting to your logging end point.  It's possible to send a test log entry with `nc`.  Example here -> http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-remote-syslog-from-embedded-or-proprietary-systems/#network-protocol.  Make sure that can connect and that the log entry goes through.